# Find all values of $x$ between 0 and $2\pi$ for which $\sin x=0.6$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find all values of $x$ between 0 and $2\pi$ for which $\sin x=0.6$.

this is what I found out from yahoo answer site 
$\sin^{-1} (0.6) = 0.64$ 
$\pi-0.64= 2.5$ 
the answer is right because I used the calculator but I would like to know how to manually solve this question without calculator. 
 
from the comment I find out the using calculator is the best but 
second question

> $\sin x=-0.45$ 
>   $\sin^-1 (-0.45) = -0.4667$ by using calculator 
>   but the right answer is $3.61,5.816$

can you show me where did I make mistake?

thx

Comment: What do you mean by "manually solve this question"? Manually calculate the value of $\arcsin(0.6)$? It is transcendental as far as i can say, so there is no way to write it other than $\arcsin(0.6)$ (or, equivalently, $\arccos(0.8)$, $\arctan(3/4)$ etc).

Comment: so, I must use calculator to solve this question? thx

Comment: There are ways of solving this without a calculator, but using one is the most efficient way. Of course, you could, e.g., solve it using the geometric definition of the sine (draw a unit circle, draw a vertical line $A$ 0.6 to the right of the center, draw a line $B$ perendicular to $A$ through the center and a line $C$ from the center to one of the intersections of $A$ with the circle, measure the angle between $B$ and $C$), look it up in a table, using some numeric approximation method or whatever, but using a calculator is actually your best bet here.

Comment: You could also expand the function $sin^{-1}(x)$ in taylor series and find an approximation by polynomial combinations.

Comment: sorrry I just edited question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a 3,4,5 triangle, the angle values are *roughly* 37,53, and 90 degrees. So since $\sin(t)= 0.6,$ the angle is about $37^\circ$. The other solution would be 
$(180-37)^\circ = 143^\circ$. You can convert the acute angle to radians as $37 \pi/180$. 
So to rough this out a little more, $37 \times 22 /(7 \times 180) \simeq 5.28 \times 11/90 \simeq 5.28/8 = .66$. I did not use a calculator in any of this calculation. My value is larger than yours since I ran $\dfrac{11}{90}$ as roughly $\dfrac{1}{8}.$

Comment: sorry, I just edited question!

Answer (score 2):

As for your edited question, note that $5.816+0.4667 = 2\pi$ (adjusted for a computational error).

Remember that $\sin(x) = \sin(x+2\pi) = sin(\pi-x)$. The calculator just gave you one of the infinite number of answers, and using these formulas you can deduce all the answers between $0$ and $2\pi$.